# Is it a security risk for app users to see the "payKey" that is returned by the Paypal API?

Tags: security, paypal

If a malicious user were to see the `payKey` token that is returned by the Paypal API, is there anything bad they could do with it?

Or does Paypal only allow my credentials to make queries against `payKeys` that are generated for my app?

Answer (score 2):

No. The payKey expires in three hours and is available to your API user only.
In Express Checkout this is available as the 'token', and it's perfectly fine for this to be visible.